# I want to pass different variables each time to dynamically created buttons in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, database

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
$time=$row[0];
$name=$row[1];
$pat_id=$row[2];
?>
<div class="col-12 shadow m-2">
   <ul class=" list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item">
         <div class="d-flex m-0 p-0 justify-content-around text-justify">
            <div>
               <?php echo $time; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="Name">
               <?php echo $pat_id.$name; ?>
            </div>
            <div>
               </a> Cancel </a><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-sm" ><i class="fa fa-minus" style="font-size:14px;"></i> </button>
            </div>
            <div>
               <form method="get"  action="sample.php">
                  <input type="hidden" name="patient" value=<?php $name ?>>
                  </a> ADD </a><button type="submit"   href="sample.html" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-sm"  id="clickbtn"><i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:14px;"></i> </button>
            </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<?php
   }
   ?>
</div>
```

here i want to pass  variables to next page in the add button and remove the variables passed in the cancel button but it was only working for the last button

Comment: why button has `href`???As well as `hidden` input has no mean if you have used `get` method.it will added as query-string anyway.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using get form, you could just form an URL with query parameters

```
<a href="sample.php?patient=<?=$name?>">Add</a>
```

Comment: Thank you it's working,and in CANCEL button  i want to send the parameters  to a 
PHP function how can i do that

Comment: you can have both Add and Cancel go to the same php file, but with different query parameters
<a href="sample.php?action=add&patient=<?=name?>">Add</a>
<a href="sample.php?action=cancel&patient=<?=name?>">Cancel</a>